# Commandline tools not installed with Server.app on Mavericks

Tags: server.app

I installed the Server.app from the App Store to use the bundeled postgres DB:

```
sudo serveradmin start postgres
```

Then I found out, that the commandline tool "serveradmin" (and others) have not been installed as implied by other postings.

Was this a change by Apple, or did I miss something?

Comment: Commandline tools should be installed by default on OS X server. You can always install them manually by running `xcode-select --install` in the Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I found the path. The path to the [server tools](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH15563) is:

```
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/serveradmin
```

I think I was too impatient and did not wait for `locate.updatedb` to complete.